# Writing an Apache Camel route in YAML that uses nested beans

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to translate the following route snippet from the Spring XML dsl:

```
<bean id="inputSource1" class="com.company.CustomBean">
  <property name="url" value="file:///home/inbox/my-source.ttl"/>
  <property name="serializationFormat" value="turtle"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="triples" class="com.company.AnotherDifferentCustomBean">
  <property name="resources">
    <list>
      <ref bean="inputSource1"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

...
```

These Beans correspond to the following Java code:

```
public class CustomBean{
    private String url;
    private String serializationFormat; 
    ... 
    ...
}

public class AnotherDifferentCustomBean{
    private List<CustomBean> resources;
    ...
    ...
}
```

A custom Bean is referenced inside another custom bean. The 'triples' bean is then referenced in the route (not shown) through the #bean:triples syntax.

This works using the Spring XML dsl but i am unsure on how to express the same snippet using the YAML dsl.

I have tried looking at the Apache Camel YAML documentation but i was not able to understand how to express my particular need.